# Combining multiple columns into one- SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am trying to make one table value function in Sql Server. Here I have 3 columns and i want to merge them  into one column lets say "new". This new column should show the name of 3 columns if they have  value as 1.For example for row one it should display Isprod, for row 2 it should display IsCompetProd and so on.

```
 IsProd IsCompetProd       IsOther
    1            0             0
    0            1             0
    0            0             1
    1            0             0
```

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please post your code in your question by editing it.

Comment: @shree.pat18 actually i searched it but couldn't figure out how to start it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

```
SELECT CASE WHEN IsProd=1 THEN 'IsProd'
            WHEN IsCompetProd=1 THEN 'IsCompetProd'
            WHEN IsOther=1  THEN 'IsOther'
        END [New]
FROM table1
```

Answer (score 1):

If I am getting what you want. Use a case statement. Try this:

```
SELECT
    tbl.*,
    (
    CASE 
        WHEN IsProd=1
        THEN 'IsProd'
        WHEN IsCompetProd=1
        THEN 'IsCompetProd'
        WHEN IsOther=1
        THEN 'IsOther'
        ELSE 'None'
    END 
    )AS newColumn       
FROM
    tbl
```